# how to find all roots of this non-linear equation in some range?

Tags: maple

I can't figure how to tell Maple to give me all root of

```
 eq:=tan(sqrt(lam)*Pi)=sqrt(lam);
```

This is what I tried

```
 RootFinding:-Analytic(eq,lam,re=0..100,im=0..0);
```

Nothing

```
 Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(eq,0..100);
```

gives  `[0]`

```
 fsolve(eq,lam,lam=0..100);
```

gives only one root  `55.61535492`

Is there other functions one can try? The roots are, using Mathematica:

```
   NSolve[Tan[Sqrt[lam] *Pi]==Sqrt[lam]&&0<lam<100,lam]
```

which gives

```
 {1.66438,5.63138,11.6225,19.6189,29.6171,41.616,55.6154,71.6149,89.6146}
```

How can one get the above result in Maple 2017.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restart;
eq := tan(sqrt(lam)*Pi) = sqrt(lam):

Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(eq, 0..100, numeric);

       [1.664382913, 5.631380410, 11.62250178, 19.61888190,
        29.61705752, 41.61601074, 55.61535492, 71.61491703,
        89.61461020]
```